# bind - permission denied while writting slave zone file

Tags: bind, ubuntu-16.04

System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Synopsis:

```
#chmod 777 /etc/bind/slave
#chmod 777 /etc/bind
#service bind9 restart
#tail /var/log/syslog | grep dump                                                                                       
Aug 23 07:14:45 appserver named[25251]: dumping master file: /etc/bind/slave/tmp-IDIdwXAG2I: open: permission denied
```

What is happening here???

Comment: This question is related and the solution is the same: https://askubuntu.com/questions/926113/zone-afxr-fails-on-permission-error-dumping-master-file-etc-bind-zones-tmp-y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that the `named` process is unable to create a file in the `/etc/bind/slave/` directory.

First of all `/etc` is really a rather unorthodox location for regular services to have write access.
Normally you would use a directory under `/var/lib` or `/var/cache` depending on the type of data.

Regarding why your extremely liberal permissions (not at all a good idea) do not help, I would guess *Apparmor* (more likely for Ubuntu) or *SELinux* has a profile for BIND which is based around reasonable assumptions (see above) for which file paths need to be writable by `named`. This applies in addition to filesystem permissions.

I would suggest that you simply move the writable files to a more sane location.

Comment: The very same config was working some months ago. I didn't touch it. By the way, of course I did not have 777 permission on /etc - I just wanted to try this before I post a question here.

Comment: @nagylzs Check your logs, I'm guessing Apparmor is yelling at you for trying to do things that are disallowed.  Either way, I would suggest doing things right instead of persisting with this bad idea.

Comment: Yes, that was it. After adding /etc/bind/slave rw and reloading the profile, it started to work. I agree - these files should not go under /etc/bind. But this was the default config given by the VPS provider, and already had some files in it. I guess having a writable DNS slave dir is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above just well explained the cause. There is a relative path defined in 
`/etc/bind/named.conf.options`, which is `directory "/var/cache/bind`.

So what I suggest to do is store your slave zone fiels to a more sane directory which is defined in your `named.conf.local` file, and give the ownership of the directory to bind group or give the write permission to bind group,

like:

```
mkdir /var/cache/bind/slaves
chown bind:bind /var/cache/bind/slaves
```